# Bash generate random numbers from pool of numbers

Tags: bash

I want to generate a random number from given list

For example if I give the numbers

```
1,22,33,400,400,23,12,53 etc.
```

I want to select a random number from the given numbers.

Comment: Put them in an array, rand mod the size of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find an exact duplicate of this. So here goes my attempt, exactly what [`123`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4923629/123) mentions in comments. The solution is portable across shell variants and does not make use of any `shell` binaries to simplify performance.

You can run the below commands directly on the console.

```
# Read the elements into bash array, with IFS being the de-limiter for input
IFS="," read -ra randomNos <<< "1,22,33,400,400,23,12,53"

# Print the random numbers using the '$RANDOM' variable built-in modulo with 
# array length.
printf "%s\n" "${randomNos[ $RANDOM % ${#randomNos[@]}]}"
```

As per the comments below, if you want to ignore a certain list of numbers from a range to select; do the approach as below

```
#!/bin/bash

# Initilzing the ignore list with the numbers you have mentioned
declare -A ignoreList='([21]="1" [25]="1" [53]="1" [80]="1" [143]="1" [587]="1" [990]="1" [993]="1")'

# Generating the random number
randomNumber="$(($RANDOM % 1023))"

# Printing the number if it is not in the ignore list
[[ ! -n "${ignoreList["$randomNumber"]}" ]] && printf "%s\n" "$randomNumber"
```

You can save it in a `bash` variable like

```
randomPortNumber=$([[ ! -n "${ignoreList["$randomNumber"]}" ]] && printf "%s\n" "$randomNumber")
```

Remember associative-arrays need bash version ≥4 to work.

Comment: I don't think that arrays are portable across shells.

Comment: @123: Yes I could have done that, wanted to demo how the exact comma separated input could be turned into an outcome like this.

Comment: @TomFenech: didn't know arrays are not portable, which variant doesn't support it? Can you elaborate the same?

Comment: Thank you for answers.
I want to generate a port to use. This port can not be 22,21 etc but must in rage 1 - 1024

Comment: @Inian Fair enough

Comment: @Inian sh doesn't support arrays.

Comment: @Dr.JoeBeer  Can you elaborate a bit more on this, you wanted a number from the list you provided right?

Comment: @Dr.JoeBeer: The above command produces random numbers in the sample input you have provided from.

Comment: Hello @Inian 

I want to generate a random Number between 1 and 1024 but the number  not allowed is 21, 25, 53, 80, 143, 443, 587, 990, 993, 2008, 8000, 10011, 30033, 41144

Comment: That's rather different from what's in your question. Maybe `do r=$((1+(RANDOM%1023))); until grep -qvwf /etc/protocols <<<"$r"` but this is completely untested.

Comment: Wht do you specify 2008, 8000, 10011, 30033, 41144 when you talk about 1-1024

Comment: BÄM, thank oyu so much! I read the code and now i understand how i works, thank you!